# Mysql Bug? Inverting 0 is inconsistent

Tags: mysql

So really I'm just curious as to what the cause of this is or if this is truly a bug that needs to be submitted to the MySQL development team.

These Queries should be equivalent (they can be hard to read):

```
SELECT !0, !!0, !!!0, !!!!0, !!!!!0, !!!!!!0;
SELECT NOT 0, NOT NOT 0, NOT NOT NOT 0, NOT NOT NOT NOT 0, NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT 0, NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT 0;
SELECT !(0), !(!(0)), !(!(!(0))), !(!(!(!(0)))), !(!(!(!(!(0))))), !(!(!(!(!(!(0))))));
```

I would expect these to return:

```
true, false, true, false, true, false
```

The first 2 do, but the last returns:

```
true, true, false, false, true, true
```

Can anyone explain this?

---

If anyone is curious, this originated from a question posed to me. Because 0 is treated as false and 1 as true, you can use a field - lets call it bool_field - like this:

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE bool_field
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE !bool_field
```

Frequently, if I want to make sure something is treated as a boolean (generically not language specific), but do not want to invert it's value, I write it as this:

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE !!bool_field
```

This lead to a really weird pattern and finally to the question above.

---

MySQL version is 5.5.4

Comment: the last one returns `1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0` to me. which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: ^^ Me too, but the first returns `1,1,0,0,1,1` on 5.6.29 (also checked 5.5 on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7d/1035)

Comment: It's working fine for me. Are you sure about your conclusions?

Comment: Seems to be based on version, the link Guido posted to a MySQL bug hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MySQL bug report has already been filed for this… 6 years ago!

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55477

Comment: Nice find, didn't know about that bug. It actually explains a few strange effects I've seen in queries with multiple operators.

Comment: I'm guessing we are just behind on our MySQL version.  I had no idea how to search for this issue, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**MariaDB also works fine**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT !(0), !(!(0)), !(!(!(0))), !(!(!(!(0)))), !(!(!(!(!(0))))), !(!(!(!(!(!(0))))));
+------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+
| !(0) | !(!(0)) | !(!(!(0))) | !(!(!(!(0)))) | !(!(!(!(!(0))))) | !(!(!(!(!(!(0)))))) |
+------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+
|    1 |       0 |          1 |             0 |                1 |                   0 |
+------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
+---------------------+
| VERSION()           |
+---------------------+
| 10.1.10-MariaDB-log |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Actually no, try `SELECT !0,!!0;`

Comment: and this :-) -  SELECT !0, ! !0;

Comment: Yes, the space makes a difference, the bug referenced i Guido's answer explains why :)

Answer (score 0):

I have chat with the MariaDB Dev Team and they send me this.

```
!0   = negate zero = 1.
! !0 = negate (negate 0) = negate 1 = 0,
!!0  = negate negate zero = is/like zero = 1.
```